# Android Apps Debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I use Android Studio to make my android apps.

How do I debug the apps using my phone? I don't want to use emulator, but I don't see any option in Android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

in click Edit Configurations

then  change the yellow circled to USB devices

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will use both.

Comment: I don't think Android Studio is as buggy as you say - you might have been right about the early preview versions, but this criticism went out of date already

Comment: I answered it in September of 2013 Anyhow i will update the answer. Thanks for bringing it.